# How to collide using OOP JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, collision-detection

I am making a game(shooting game) using OOP javascript for my project. I already moved(player) and make the enemy disappear at the edge of the container. Now, I want to collide with the shooter(player) and enemy and display the message "Game Over". Here is my code of `enemy.js` and `shooter.js`. Also, my `container.js`.

container.js

```
class Container{
    constructor(){
        this.containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
    }
    initialization(){
        this.shooterElement = document.getElementsByClassName("shooter")[0];
        let containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
        this.backgroundElement = document.getElementsByClassName("background")[0];
        this.background = new Background(this.backgroundElement);
        this.shooter = new Shooter(this.shooterElement);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>this.shooter.buttonGotPressed(e));
        let enemyElement = document.getElementsByClassName("enemy")[0];
        this.enemies = [];
        setInterval(function(){
            var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
            var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 550) + 1;
            this.enemy = new Enemy({parentElement: containerElement, leftPosition: left, topPosition: top});
        },400)
        this.enemies.push(this.enemy); 
    }
}
let container = new Container();
container.initialization();
```

enemy.js

```
class Enemy{
     constructor({parentElement,leftPosition, topPosition }){
        let enemyElement = document.createElement("div");
        this.enemyElement = enemyElement;
        this.leftPosition = leftPosition;
        this.topPosition = topPosition;
        this.containerHeight = 600;
        this.y = 15;
        this.height = 40;
        this.width = 50;
        this.enemyElement.style.left = this.leftPosition + 'px';
        this.enemyElement.style.top= this.topPosition + 'px'; 
        this.enemyElement.style.height = this.height + 'px';
        this.enemyElement.style.width = this.width + 'px';
        this.enemyElement.style.position = "absolute";
        this.enemyElement.style.background="url(images/enemy3.png)";   
        console.log(enemyElement)
        parentElement.appendChild(this.enemyElement);
        this.containerCollision = this.containerCollision.bind(this);
        setInterval(this.containerCollision, 100);
    }
    containerCollision(){
        if(this.topPosition >= this.containerHeight - this.width ){
            this.enemyElement.style.display="none";
        }
        this.topPosition = this.topPosition + this.y;
        this.enemyElement.style.top = this.topPosition + 'px';    
    }
}
```

shooter.js (this is the player)

```
class Shooter {
  constructor(shooterElement){
        this.shooterElement = shooterElement;
        this.shooterleftPosition = 300;
        this.shootertopPosition = 555;
        this.containerWidth = 600;
        this.width = 30;
        this.height = 40;
        this.x = 5;
        this.y = 1;
        this.shooterElement.style.left = this.shooterleftPosition + 'px';
        this.shooterElement.style.top = this.shootertopPosition + 'px';
        this.buttonGotPressed = this.buttonGotPressed.bind(this);
    }
    buttonGotPressed(e){
        console.log(e);
        if(e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
            console.log(e.key);
            if(this.shooterleftPosition <= 0){
                this.shooterleftPosition = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            this.shooterleftPosition = this.shooterleftPosition - this.x;                
            }
            console.log(this.shooterleftPosition)
            this.shooterElement.style.left = this.shooterleftPosition +'px'; 
        }
        if(e.key == "ArrowRight"){
            this.shooterleftPosition = this.shooterleftPosition + this.x;
            this.shooterElement.style.left = this.shooterleftPosition +'px';
            if(this.shooterleftPosition >= this.containerWidth - this.width){
                this.shooterleftPosition = this.containerWidth - this.width;
                this.shooterElement.style.left = this.leftPosition + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
}
     Now, How do I detect and collide shooter(player) and enemy and display the message/alert "Game Over". If the enemy touches the shooter(player). Here is pic too.
```

[How do i know enemy touched the player and display game over in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erBdh.png)

What I tried to detect the collision of player and enemy

```
 collidingShooter(){
            if (this.enemies.push(this.enemy)>1) 
            {
(
                 ([this.enemies][this.enemy].top <= this.shootertopPosition + 50) &&
            ([this.enemies][this.enemy].top >= this.shootertopPosition) &&
             ([this.enemies][this.enemy].left >= this.shooterleftPosition) &&
            ([this.enemies][this.enemy].left <= this.shooterleftPosition+ 50) 

)
            console.log("hitttt");
            this.enemies.splice(this.enemy,1);
           // this.shooterElement.splice(1);
            }

         }
```

Comment: Hi Vatsat, can you add what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ok, and what is your problem?

Comment: I added what i have tried so far. :)

Comment: My problem is that the player and enemy does not collide. As you can see in the pic and also in the code...there is no collision detection for the player(shooter) and enemy.

Comment: You tried and it gives you an error or it doesn't work? Maybe you should spend some time and think what is wrong.

Comment: @Konowy It does not give me any error. I couldn`t find any solution so far to make them collide. I don`t know what is wrong in my collision code or we have another method to collide player and enemy?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you messed something up here
First of all you use array in the wrong way:

```
[this.enemies][this.enemy].top
```

What it does:
Creates new array with one element (which is this.enemies array), now it converts this.enemy to a string = 'object Object' and tries to find a key in this new array, which propably returns undefined and now it tries to get top of undefined.
What you probably wanted to do is:

```
this.enemies[this.enemies.indexOf(this.enemy)].top
```

But even though it has no oop sense.
What I would do:

```
function checkCollision() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.enemies.length; i++) {
    if (areColliding(this.shooter, this.enemies[i])) {
      console.log('hit')
    }
  }
}

function areColliding(o1, o2) {
  if (o1.top <= o2.top + o2.height &&
    o1.top >= o2.top &&
    o1.left <= o2.left + o2.width &&
    o1.left >= o2.left) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

There are better collision algorithms than aabb and even if you want to do this in this way, your game can get very slow if you have thousands of enemies. There is algorithm to split game world in to smaller rectangles and check for collision inside them.